# Heroku: Pushing an update from a source branch that is not main

Tags: python, git, heroku, discord.py

I am trying to upload my app to heroku but the `heroku/python` buildpack does not build my app and says it is not compatible with it, I have a `Procfile` and a `requirements.txt` file. all the required files are added and committed, the app runs perfectly on my local machine.

This is the requirements file:
[image]

This is the Procfile:
[image]

This is the output:

```
$ git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 197, done.
Counting objects: 100% (197/197), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (189/189), done.
Writing objects: 100% (197/197), 51.94 KiB | 2.16 MiB/s, done.
Total 197 (delta 93), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 644afa937ebb796a0ba0e2c8f3a459f4accbac36
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 644afa937ebb796a0ba0e2c8f3a459f4accbac36
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to botsenior.
remote:
```

The folder itself looks like so:
[image]

**I have tried anything in my power to fix this. I Deleted the heroku app several times and created it again, I tried changing the module versions in the requirements.txt file but nothing seems to work. Help would be greatly appreciated**
*note: I am pushing from a source branch that is not the master branch on my local git repo, but I am pushing it to the master branch on the heroku remote repository. I don't know if this is a problem but I thought it would be important to specify this*

Comment: `git push heroku master` you are not pushing from a source branch. You are pushing the local master branch to the remote master branch.

Comment: @TinNguyen the master is the master branch of the remote repository, I am pushing from my local Different branch. I forgot to specify I am already checked out onto my desired branch.

Comment: With that command you are still pushing the local master branch to the remote master branch. If you want to push the local dev branch to the remote master branch you do: `git push heroku dev:master`

Comment: @TinNguyen you are amazing thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to push from a local branch that is not master you have to specify the source and the target branches and separate them with a colon:

```
git push heroku <source>:<target>
```